# General Form of Rectangular Prism in 3D Graphing

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I am learning Multivariable Calculus and ran into a lot of shapes that we can graph using a 3D grapher.

e.g. Paraboloid x²/a² + y²/b² = z

I wonder if we can graph a rectangular prism or a cube? What would its general form look like?

Comment: A closed surface cannot be defined by an explicit equation $z=f(x,y)$, nor can vertical faces.

Comment: You can graph it but you cannot define all faces as $z=f(x,y)$, as Yves mentioned.